# wpdb undefined when submitting a form through admin-post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to process a form I added to a post, using a plugin that I made but I keep having errors saying that wpdb is undefined. I don't understand since I'm sending the form to admin-post.php to then call my php function via a hook.... Here is how I call admin-post.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="partage_form">
```

And now the code inside the pluggin

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_partage_form', 'partage_to_db' );
add_action( 'admin_post_partage_form', 'partage_to_db' );

function partage_to_db(){
global $wpdp;
$lang_string="";
foreach ($_POST["langues_group"] as $langue){
    $lang_string.=$langue . ",";
}
$lang_string = substr($lang_string, 0, -1);

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO partages (
    TITRE_PARTAGE,
    ETABLISSEMENT_PARTAGE,
    SITE_WEB_PARTAGE,
    RESSOURCE_PARTAGE,
    COURRIEL_PARTAGE,
    CATEGORIE_PARTAGE,
    DATE_CREATION_PARTAGE,
    DATE_DEPOT_PARTAGE,
    IMAGE_PATH_PARTAGE,
    FICHIERS_PATH_PARTAGE,
    LIEN_PARTAGE,
    DESCRIPTION_LIEN_PARTAGE,
    LANGUES_PARTAGE,
    MOTS_CLES_PARTAGE)
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", 
  $_POST["titre_partage"],
  $_POST["etablissement_partage"],
  $_POST["site_web_partage"],
  $_POST["ressource_partage"],
  $_POST["courriel_partage"],
  $_POST["categorie_partage"],
  $_POST["date_creation_partage"],
  $_POST["date_depot_partage"],
  $_POST["image_partage"],
  $_POST["fichiers_partage"],
  $_POST["lien_partage"],
  $_POST["description_lien_partage"],
  $lang_string,
  $_POST["mots_cles_partage"]));
}
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Line 5 has a typo. It should be ```global $wpdb```. The last character should be "b" not "p".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this typo in first line of your function.

```
function partage_to_db()
{
    global $wpdb;  // Was $wpdp before
```

Comment: We all do this sometimes ;)